# Printing bit representation of unsigned char* single_char;

Tags: c

Expanding my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755940/how-to-change-4-bits-in-unsigned-char)..

```
unsigned char* s_char = data + offset;
(*s_char) = size_t(((*s_char) & 0xf0)) | new_doff;
```

How to print s_char's bit representation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a printf converter to print in binary format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format)

Comment: Confirmed. Unfortunally, that question didn't came up in search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to manually print it using something like:

```
  printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", *s_char & 0x80, *s_char & 0x40, ..., *s_char & 0x01);
```

Comment: Ha, they indeed use it: http://google.com/codesearch?as_q=%22%25d%25d%25d%25d%25d%25d%25d%25d%22

Answer (score 1):

I would use a type cast to int like

```
unsigned char* s_char = data + offset;  
(*s_char) = size_t(((*s_char) & 0xf0)) | new_doff;  
int s_char_int;
s_char_int = (int)s_char;
```

Then you can print it to the console or whatever else you want